# Java: Detect and remove deadlocks on a schedule

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-7

currently working on a system written in javaEE (EJBs) where i want to be able to detect and handle database deadlocks. Database being PGSQL
I was initially thinking of creating a ScheduledBean with the @Schedule annotation to run at @Startup to poll every few minute for deadlocks
(which would be running an SQL statement to detect the deadlocks). However i'm not so sure as to whether this would be the right thing to do, since
polling could have some cost on performance. I would rather do this at the Java level rather than in the SQL Server level.

Any advice is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need or pass information from the Java application to the SQL statement? If not, I'd suggest to handle it completely in the database, by either adding a trigger, if the check should occur on inserts/updates or something like [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/pgagent.html) to execute on a scheduled basis.

If you still want to do it from your Java EE application, then easiest thing would to use the [EJB Timer Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples004.htm).

Comment: I agree. I would rather do it on the database side. However the requirement is to have control via theJava side. Yes EJB Timer service is ideal. thanks.